# Reason behind the clarity

Tags: video-quality

I have seen many videos with nearly same size and same length, but the clarity of the video changes or differs. I wanted to know the reason or fact behind this.

Comment: The Q isn't clear. Are you asking about image quality or focus/DoF? Can you illustrate with screenshots?

Comment: I am asking about video quality. For instance, consider a video with two different type but the size is almost the same, then why is the one blurred then other?

Comment: Attach examples.

Comment: I always download the movies after 2-3days of realise with nearly 700MB thinking that it will be clear, and the same movie after a month with same size of nearly 700MB gives a more clear view to the one earlier download.

Comment: That probably comes down to source quality.

Comment: But anyways it is related to the question only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be too many factors involved to properly answer your question. One is the image quality of the source footage, there are objective and subjective parameters influencing this. Examples:

- proper lighting
- set design
- image framing

Etc.

Then there are technical parameters in the image aqcuisition involved:

- quality of the cameras sensor
- quality of the post production (grading etc)

Then there are parameters in the delivery:

- delivery Codec
- compressibility of the images

As for the "subjective" parameters, there are a lot of psychological things involved: a lot of people consider these things as "better" while really only being a matter of taste:

- sharpened image
- enhanced contrasts
- less grain

So unless being more specific, your question IMHO cannot be answered.